# Optimizing a giant mysql table

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a giant mysql table which is growing at all the time. It's recording chat data.

this what my table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `channel` VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `username` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    `message` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `username` (`username`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2582573
;
```

Indexing the username is kinda important because queries for a username can take like 5 seconds otherwise.

Is there anyway of optimizing this table even more to prepare it for huge amounts of data. 
So that even 100m rows won't be a problem.

Comment: you may want to consider other solutions than a relation db for cases like this.

Comment: What alternatives would there be besides just .txt files?

Comment: The optimal indexes for this table really depend on the actual queries you are running. For example, if you specify "ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC" and/or "WHERE t.timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 DAY"  etc. in your queries, then an index on \`timestamp\` may be beneficial. If your query includes equality predicate on username, then you probably want a composite index "ON log(username,\`timestamp\`)" in place of an index on the singleton "username" column. Also, *partitioning* can sometimes help in managing huge tables.

Comment: Yeah I get that. Currently username is fine timestamp will probably need to be indexed in the future aswell, but I don't access data that way yet.

Comment: While your table is large, MySQL is quite happy with tables up to tens of millions at the very least, really 2.5m is not much for MySQL. Please read this link, it was recommend to me a few weeks ago and gives some excellent advice re:indexes. http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: Once indexed, the size of the table won't matter. Tested on 80m rows table. ran the same query on prod (80m rows) and local (1000 rows) table, prod execution time was slightly faster thanks to linux (my PC is windows).

Comment: I'm less worried about the speed of the query but more worried about the memory usage just growing and growing because usernames/timestamps need to be indexed

Comment: It depends on what you are going to do with that table. `channel` could be "outsourced" to a separate table and replaced by a FK `channel_id`. `message` could also be in an separate table (vertical partitioning) if you rarely query that column.

Comment: You may want to use numerical user IDs, never strings, as those are much, much more painful to index. Remember to adhere to the basics of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) unless you have a compelling reason to diverge. You should index on User ID, obviously, a table scan would be cripplingly slow otherwise, but it's odd you're not indexing on channel. Also, **use UTF-8** whenever possible.

Comment: IDs for usernames would be painful because I would have a 2nd table which would have to be constantly updated aswell and will probably have a lot of failed queries because the user id is unique and I only get the user ID when I read a message nowhereelse

Comment: @danielps1, you could take a look at a [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) such as [CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Will you have more than 4 billion rows?  If not, use `INT UNSIGNED`, saving 4 bytes per row.  Plus another 4 bytes for each row in the secondary index.

```
`channel` VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL,
`username` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
```

Normalize each -- that is, replace this by, say, a `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` and have a mapping between them.  Savings: lots.

```
INDEX `username` (`username`)
```

That becomes user_id, saving even more.

Smaller --> more cacheable --> faster.

What other queries will you have?

"Memory usage" -- For InnoDB, set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of available RAM.  Then, let it worry about what is in memory, what it not.  Once the table is too big to be cached, you should shrink the data (as I mentioned above) and provide 'good' indexes (as mentioned in other comments) and perhaps structure the table for "locality of reference" (without knowing all the queries, I can't address this).

You grumbled about using IDs instead of strings...  Let's take a closer look at that.  How many distinct usernames are there?  channels?  How does the data come in -- do you get one row at a time, or batches?  Is something doing direct `INSERTs` or feeding to some code that does the `INSERTs`?  Could there be a `STORED PROCEDURE` to do the normalization and insertion?  If you need hundreds of rows inserted per second, then I can discuss how to do both, and do them efficiently.

You did not ask about `PARTITIONs`.  I do *not* recommend it for a simple `username` query.

2.5M rows is about the 85th percentile.  100M rows is more exciting -- 98th percentile.

Comment: The data comes in 1 row everytime, a stored procedure would certainly be possible and good. channels and usernames are in theory same in total. What that total is? hard to guess but twitch.tv probably has a millions of users. but in reality I will have only around 50k channels at the very maximum. This was already very helpful thank you.

Comment: 50K out of 2500K -- sounds like a good candidate for normalizing.  `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (3 bytes, 16M limit) sounds like the right size of int to use.

Comment: okay. assuming I use IDs for my username and channels. I can't get those IDs except when inserting data so I have another table that holds ID and username where ID has to be indexed aswell. and then I index channel and username in the big table. Would that really be more efficent than just keeping 2 varchars(25) or so in the big table? Also I would have to do an extra insert for every message for the ID username table, because I can't get the ID otherwise. channel and username are the same basicly btw. they are in relation in the big table

Comment: It depends.  Your table is perhaps under 1GB today, but expected to grow to 30GB?  What is the buffer_pool_size?  70% of RAM?  Performance will change after the table and its indexes is too big to fit in the buffer_pool.  My tips will postpone that day.  Do the math.  Let's see your queries -- maybe all of them will work well even if the table is not fully cached.

Comment: I would say this would be my slowest and hardest query to execute. SELECT channel, timestamp, username, message
        FROM log AS r1 JOIN
           (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *
                (SELECT MAX(id) FROM log)) AS id)
                AS r2
        WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
        AND channel = ?
        AND username = ?
        ORDER BY r1.id ASC
        LIMIT 1;

Comment: For that query, `INDEX(channel, username, id)` or `INDEX(username, channel, id)` should make it run a lot faster.  If not, open a new question and provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.